# È più corretto dire "all'ora di pranzo" oppure "nell'ora di pranzo"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In un esercizio di italiano (presente nei compiti delle vacanze di mio figlio) c'era la seguente frase da completare che mi ha fatto sorgere dubbi:

> Ti hanno chiamato ______'ora di pranzo.

Mio figlio propone:

> Ti hanno chiamato **all**'ora di pranzo.

mentre io ribatto che sia più corretto dire:

> Ti hanno chiamato **nell**'ora di pranzo.

Sono accettabili entrambe? Altrimenti, quale delle due è corretta?

Comment: Penso siano entrambe corrette, ma a me la seconda non suona molto naturale. Ti chiederesti "a che ora hanno chiamato" o "in che ora hanno chiamato?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mio avviso sono entrambe corrette, ma propendo per la prima.

"**All'ora di pranzo**" lascia intendere che hanno chiamato nel periodo comunemente inteso come quello in cui si pranza (che è abbastanza soggettivo: può essere alle 12:30, come alle 13.00, come alle 13:30, a seconda delle abitudini e delle zone).

"**Nell'ora**" dà più l'idea di qualcosa di oggettivo e temporalmente delimitato in senso stretto: "è successo nell'ora della ricreazione" / "è successo nell'ora della pausa pranzo", assumendo la ricreazione o la pausa pranzo come eventi che durano esattamente un'ora, e che è la stessa per tutti all'interno del contesto.
Anche nel caso degli esempi, però, ritengo preferibile dire "durante l'ora della ricreazione", o "durante la ricreazione", per snellire la sintassi.

Comment: Eccolo che è arrivato, il downvote, peraltro ingiustificato. Vedo che le vecchie abitudini di questo sito non si sono perse :-)

Comment: Anche la domanda ha ricevuto un voto negativo e a me piacerebbe sapere il motivo. Ultimamente praticamente tutte le domande che si stanno facendo su questo sito stanno ricevendo dei voti negativi senza nessun commento che ne spieghi la ragione. Vedi [questo post sul Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/should-downvoters-leave-a-comment-to-explain-the-reason-of-their-downvote).

Comment: Grazie @Charo. [_padding_]

Comment: @Andrea Peraltro anche voto negativo sulla domanda. Non discuto, ci mancherebbe, ma tanto, come ha detto Charo, è un vecchio problema che contrappone due scuole di pensiero...

Comment: @Charo Avete provato a contattare lo staff di SE per investigare su un eventuale "serial voting"? Il fatto che ogni nuova domanda abbia esattamente un downvote mi sembra parecchio sospetto. Sono sempre stato della scuola di pensiero che un commento per un downvote non sia necessario, ma in questo caso potrebbe esserci sotto qualcos'altro.